# How to color elements within Graphics[Table[]] independently?

Tags: color, list-manipulation, geometry

I've used a `Table[]` to generate multiple rounded squares, with `Rectangle[{m, n}, RoundingRadius -> .35]`. So far, I've been able to color all the squares with the same color, for instance, with `LightBlue`:

`Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], 
  Table[{LightBlue, Rectangle[{m, n}, RoundingRadius -> .35]}, {m, 
    5}, {n, 5}]}, Frame -> True]`

[image]

Or generate random colors for each square, for instance, with `Hue[RandomReal[]]`:

`Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], 
  Table[{Hue[RandomReal[]], 
    Rectangle[{m, n}, RoundingRadius -> .35]}, {m, 5}, {n, 5}]}, 
 Frame -> True]`

[image]

But, generally, I'd like to control the color of each of the squares independently, because I already have a vector of `Hue[#]` colors that I want to use. For instance, I'd like to use this 25 colors in correspondence to each of the `(m,n)` squares in the grid:

`m=5;
n=5;
Split@Hue[#] & /@ Range[1/(m*n), 1, 1/(m*n)]`

[image]

I've tried to do something like the following, but it doesn't seem right:

`Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], 
  Table[{c, Rectangle[{m, n}, RoundingRadius -> .35]}, {m, 5}, {n, 
    5}, {c, Split@Hue[#] & /@ Range[1/(m*n), 1, 1/(m*n)]}]}, Frame -> True]`

[image]

I've also tried to `Map[]` the colors or use a `ColorFunction->` but had no success.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks!
-Pedro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with slightly modified color code:

```
m = 5;
n = 5;
colors = Hue /@ Range[1/(m*n), 1, 1/(m*n)];

rectangles = Table[Rectangle[{m, n}, RoundingRadius -> .35], {m, 5}, {n, 5}];
```

We may use either of these, among others of course:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], {colors, Flatten@rectangles}\[Transpose]}, Frame -> True]

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Riffle[colors, Flatten@rectangles]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Reference [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) and [`Riffle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle.html).

Also possible:

```
i = 1;

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], 
  Table[{colors[[i++]], Rectangle[{m, n}, RoundingRadius -> .35]}, {m, 5}, {n, 5}]},
  Frame -> True]
```

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Wizard! I wasn't aware of `Riffle[]`. This is a simple solution :)

Comment: @Pedro Glad I could help.